# Percentage of signed up users for beta is wrong on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The percentage of users that committed to the proposal and then joined the beta, displayed in the right sidebar on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta), shows 0% for all the older proposals.

[image]

The cutoff seems to be around 90 days, all older proposals show 0% signed up, the newer proposals show a proper value.

Comment: Confirmed. I submitted the bug to the dev team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks.

A couple months ago, we changed the way that we store each site's "beta access whitelist", and the old way was accidentally made incompatible with our mechanism for fetching "% signed up for beta" stats.